Cannot sort or filter a date in bootstrap-table
I need your help again. Let me tell you.
I have created a bootstrap-table where one of its columns is a datetime that options filter and sort the data in that same column. But when I filter by a date, either by entering the value by hand or using the datepicker, it doesn't filter anything. On the other hand, if I sort the column, it doesn't work correctly either, it seems that it is actually sorted as if it were a string or something similar.
This is my code.
<table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-show-toggle="true"
       data-show-fullscreen="true"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
       data-detail-view="false"
       data-show-export="true"
       data-export-types="['json', 'xml', 'csv' , 'txt' , 'sql', 'xlsx' , 'pdf' ]"
       data-export-data-type="all"
       data-click-to-select="false"
       data-minimum-count-columns="2"
       data-show-pagination-switch="false"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-side-pagination="client"
       data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
       data-show-footer="true"
       data-filter-control="true"
       data-cache="false"
       data-show-search-clear-button="true">

<th data-field="fechaIncorporacion" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="datepicker">Fecha Incorporacion</th>

I have tried to add this attribute to the column with the date that I found in a forum, in case the problem was related to the date format, but nothing
data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD"

I have tried to define a custom search, but this does not work correctly either. From what I have been able to see, when doing new Date(dateA) of some dates that come from the controller, we get NaN
<th data-field="myDate" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="datepicker" data-sorter="myDateSorter">My Date</th>

window.myDateSorter= function myDateSorter(a, b) {
    var a = new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime();
    return a;
}

There is no attribute for the column (both sort and search) to work correctly. My slight suspicion is that perhaps the date format does not correspond to what the bootstrap-table can handle. Is there a way to configure the bootstrap-table to handle these types of "dd-mm-yyyy" dates?

The search function on the official documentation page doesn't give any results for data-date-format, so I can't tell you if that is actually supposed to do anything here.

@CBroe. Many Thanks for helping here. Yep, I really supposed, but my others approaches should work... but still no. Any idea from your side? :)

"when doing new Date(dateA) of some dates that come from the controller, we get NaN" - the Date constructor can't handle just any arbitrary date format. If your format as shown in the column is dd-mm-yyyy, then you might need to take that apart into its components first, in your custom sort function. Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript has hints/approaches.

You were right. Your analysis is correct. Finally, from the controller I pass a string in dd-mm-yyyy format, to display it in the table as I want. And then the data-sorter calls a JS function that converts that string to a date in my location. At that moment I compare them. Thank you very much @CBroe . If you decide to post your solution, I will vote positively for it.

Closure of the question as a duplicate is more appropriate in this case then, I think.
